# Change tinyint default value into 1 mysql

Tags: mysql, database, tinyint

I have a status column in my database table. **Type : tinyint(4)** and the Default value is 0. I want to change the default value to 1. How to do that?
May be this is a very simple question, but I don't know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can  do so

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I've explained above.

Comment: Looks like in phpMyAdmin there is not this possiblity

Answer (score 8):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY COLUMN col TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `Type` CHANGE `status` `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: why is '1' in quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `your_column` `your_column` TINYINT( 3 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

Comment: why '1'  in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want add any column in your table you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE Column_name  tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
```